# Laravel join tables and get max orders by users

Tags: php, laravel, web, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have 2 models `Orders` and `Users`, i want to get the list of users who ordered most with the **sum of total** as **amount**

The table structure

```
  //users
    id  name  phone_number  
    1   John  1111111111
    2   Mike  2222222222

  //orders
    id  user_id  total 
    1     1      500  
    2     1      450
    3     2      560
    4     1      850
    5     2      500

  //expected result 
    name  phone_number  orders  amount 
    John  1111111111      3      1800
    Mike  2222222222      2      1060
```

Tried with following query

```
$privilaged_users = User::leftJoin('orders', 'orders.user_id', 'users.id')
                        ->select('name','phone_number')
                        ->max('orders.user_id as orders')
                        ->groupBy('orders.user_id')
                        ->get();
```

Getting Following error

```
    SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in
 your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
 for the right syntax to use near 'as `orders`) as aggregate from `users` left 
join `orders` on `orders`.`user_id` ' at line 1 (SQL: select 
max(`orders`.`user_id` as `orders`) as aggregate from `users` left join `orders`
 on `orders`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write this query as,

```
$privilaged_users = User::leftJoin('orders', 'orders.user_id',"=", 'users.id')
                    ->select('name','phone_number',DB::raw('max(orders.total) as orders_total'))
                    ->groupBy('orders.user_id')  
                    ->get();
```

As raw query, because by default it will consider whole string as column

**EDIT**

Your problem was, you were doing group by on field which is taken inside aggregate function.

Here are some links to explain [my concern much better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql).

I have made changes in code. Please check once.

Comment: thank you for your response, tried your solution getting the same old `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation` error

Comment: yes i did same error `Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'ideal_chicken.users.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `name`, `phone_number`, max(orders.user_id) as orders from `users` left join `orders` on `orders`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null group by `orders`.`user_id`)`

Comment: try to change alias name like orders_total

Comment: try to change alias name like orders_total and try to remove this only_full_group_by mode from sql-mode in my.ini of mysql folder

Comment: there is no `only_full_group_by ` in my **my.ini** file, i ran the code in production server the error is same

Comment: *select name, phone_number, max(orders.user_id) as orders_total from users left join orders on orders.user_id = users.id where users.deleted_at is null group by orders.user_id* try running this query on mysql tool like phpmyadmin or something

Comment: `Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'ideal_chicken.users.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: I got your problem. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738926/laravel-eloquent-query) and [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)
We were doing group by on field which is taken inside aggregate function. I hope I am clear. I changed code. And here is the query *select name, phone_number, max(orders.total) as orders_total from users left join orders on orders.user_id = users.id where users.deleted_at is null group by orders.user_id* Give it a try this should work

Comment: once check my edit portion of answer you will get it

Comment: thank you, the code works only if i change `'strict' => true,` to `false`. dose it affect to project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153783/discussion-between-rahul-meshram-and-mr-robot).

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT MAX(field AS something)` is invalid syntax. Try this:

```
$privilaged_users = User::leftJoin('orders', 'orders.user_id', 'users.id')
                        ->select('name','phone_number', DB::raw('max(orders.user_id) AS orders_total'), 'orders.user_id')
                        ->groupBy('orders.user_id')
                        ->get();
```

And refer to the MAX field as "aggregate"

Comment: thank you for your response, tried your code getting `Call to a member function groupBy() on string
`

Comment: Try now, please.

Comment: getting `Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'eitansof_ideal_chicken.users.name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `name`, `phone_number`, max(orders.user_id) AS orders_total, `orders`.`user_id` from `users` left join `orders` on `orders`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null group by `orders`.`user_id`)`

Comment: Oh, you have your `sqlmode` as `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`. You need to either change the query as to place any column your `SELECT`ing in the `GROUP BY` clause, or set `strict => false` in the `mysql` array in `config/database.php`